# Cannot find product to add to Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

I have crated few products. Now I cannot find them when I am trying to add them to the Opportunity.
Products are active. They are added to a Price Book. Price Book is also active. Any idea what is required to be done?

Comment: Are you the Opportunity Owner? If not check the permission for editing opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

I found something like this myself puzzeling one time or another. I was usually able to find and use products after **pricebook entries** in the standard and at least one custom pricebook where present and active. Note you can not only activate/deactivate products but also the pricebook entries themselves.

Please check the following:

- Custom Pricebook exists and is active
- Custom Pricebook is assigned to the specific Opportunity
- Pricebook Entries exists in the Standard Pricebook and is active
- Pricebook Entries exists for the Custom Pricebook and is active
- Product is active

Answer (score 0):

In case if you enabled multi-currency in your Org you need to check your opportunity currency and product currency. The mismatch may cause the same result